# How to get the html code from tinyMCE editor using Php,Javascript

Tags: tinymce

I am the tinyMCE beginer...

i display the tinyMCE editot in browser and  make able to add the style to the textarea content

How to get the html code from tinyMCE editor using Php,Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
```

or if you know your editor id

```
tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getContent();
```