# How to extract HTML content from TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm a beginner on Javascript/TinyMCE and I try to understand how is it possible to get the HTML content from the editor, and show it with a simple alert() function.

I've this minimalist config on my HTML page :

```
<div id="tiny">
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor"
});
</script>
</div>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea id="myarea1" class="mceEditor">This will be an editor.</textarea>
</form>
```

On the [TinyMCE Website](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent), They explained that i have to use this :

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503320/how-to-get-the-html-code-from-tinymce-editor-using-php-javascript) too

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
```

I don't know why it doesn't work

Someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**I don't know why it doesn't work**

It's not working because

```
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

these statements are not being executed.

Try to follow this [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/e5caab) ....

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor"
});
```

Function for getting content ....

```
function get_editor_content() {
  // Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
  console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
  //method1 getting the content of the active editor
  alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
  //method2 getting the content by id of a particular textarea
  alert(tinyMCE.get('myarea1').getContent());
}
```

Get the content of editor on button click ...

```
<button onclick="get_editor_content()">Get content</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help. It's very well explained, I understand now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's the case? Your variable is `tinyMCE`, but you are calling `getContent()` on `tinymce`. JS is case sensitive ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution and tried some of the above then went looking more on the tinymce documentation and found this to be effective. 
***Using the tiny mce 4***

```
function getHTML()
{
   tinymce.activeEditor.on('GetContent', function(e) {
     console.log(e.content);
   });
}
```

**just call that function with an onclick and see what the results are...**
My source is:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ContentEvent

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE creates an iframe under the format '#textareaid'+'_ifr' So by using jquery we can query the HTML contents of the text area you like

the iframe id will be your textarea Id with "_ifr" appended to that. So you can extract HTML contents from tinyMce

```
$('#textareaId_ifr').contents().find("html").html();
```