# Get content from TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I'm trying to get the Content from TinyMCE, but it only returns null. The problem it's loaded in a Dialog box.
The dialog view:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="25" id="tinymce"> 
    Dette er noget tekst
        </textarea>
</form>

<input class="close" onclick="get_editor_content()" name="submit" type="submit" value="Kontakt Oline" style="float: right" id="contenttiny" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
</script>
```

The view where the dialog is opened from:

```
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="emailDialog" data-dialog-title="Kontakt/prospekt" href="/Home/tinymce">Contact US</a>

<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("<div ></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
          title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
          close: function () { $(this).remove() },
          modal: true,
          position: ['center', 40],
          minWidth: 670,
          resizable: false
        })
        .load(this.href);
    });
  });


  $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var content = tinyMCE.get('tinymce').getContent(); //$("#contenttiny").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Home/tinymce",

      data: { "content": content },

      success: function (data) {

        $("#result").html(data.nameret);
        $(".dialog").dialog("close");
      },

      error: function (data) {
        alert("There was error processing this");
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult tinymce(string content)
 {    /*Your other processing logic will go here*/
  return Json(new
  {
    nameret = content
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.


  AllowGet);
}
```

P.S. [I have used this example to create the modal dialog](http://amitraya.blogspot.dk/2012/09/modal-dialog-form-view-using-jquery.html). Which is an PartialView. It's possible to get the content from tinymce in the main index view. But not in the ajax call.

Comment: can you get the content before you close the dialogue?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to use this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023323/how-to-extract-html-content-from-tinymce-editor?rq=1 and i get the content. But i can't get it from the .close function.

Comment: can you log to console what tinyMCE.get('tinymce') contains?

Comment: The output looks like this '<p>Dette er noget tekst</p>'

Comment: hmm, tinyMCE.get('tinymce') should contain an object

Comment: Yes. that was also what i thought. And the reason i have asked here. any thought

Comment: can you show me what content holds right before you do the ajax call?

Comment: Only this "content: " ↵    Dette er noget tekst↵". Which is the text thats default.

Comment: is that  the default content that the editor holds, or is it another content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was rather simple. The reason was that the tinymce is returning html text, which per default is not allowed. The solution was to put `[ValidateInput(false)]` over the Controller method.