# Importing HTML Content to TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, laravel, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor. Although I reviewed all the topics in Stackoverflow on the website, I could not show my HTML content with "setContent". My content was included as HTML, but it appears to be plain text.

Script code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init change', function () {
                editor.setContent('{{ @$post->body }}');
                editor.save();
            });
        },
        height: 400,
        branding: false,
        selector: '#sy-editor',
        element_format : 'html',
        plugins: 'print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap emoticons',

        menubar: "",
        toolbar: 'image media link | formatselect | bold italic underline | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | table charmap emoticons | fullscreen',
        save_enablewhendirty: true,
        save_onsavecallback: function () {
            var body = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
        },
        automatic_uploads: true,
        image_title: true,
        images_upload_url: '{{ route('news.image.upload') }}',
        file_picker_types: 'image',
        file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');

            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

            input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                reader.onload = function () {
                    var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(file.name, file, base64);

                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});
                };
            };
            input.click();
        },
        language_url : '{{ asset('scripts/tinymc-lang-tr_TR.js') }}',
        language: 'tr_TR',
        content_css: [
            '{{ asset('styles/panel.css') }}'
        ],
    });
</script>
```

[The output is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIlJJ.png)

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know what I want to do with this, so can I write a little more detail?

Comment: I'm using the TinyMCE editor and I want to display the data I will pull from the database with "setContent" as HTML.

Comment: Maybe there are similar problems here?[How about this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023323/how-to-extract-html-content-from-tinymce-editor?rq=1)

Comment: I don't want to export. I want to import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need some HTML inside input in Larvel blade(you added a laravel tag so i assumed you work with laravel blade here) you can do it like so:

```
  <textarea id="sy-editor">
      {{ $post->body }}
  </textarea>
```

You dont need to initialize content in javascript

Comment: This way, the content does not come to the TinyMCE editor.

Comment: Oh i see - you probably never gona see html tags inside tiny MCE editor BUT it exists ;) check on menu view->source_code